# Return XML tag attribute when tag value matches input using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, google-gadget, xmldom

I am working with the XML code shown below.  I have already requested and retrieved the code.  I need to write a function that will:
  1) receive the inputted code
  2) dynamically return the subnational2-code in the database that corresponds with the subnational1-code="US-MI" and the tag value "Kent"

```
<result>
  <location country-code="US" subnational1-code="US-TX" subnational2-code="US-TX-263">Kent</location>
  <location country-code="US" subnational1-code="US-VA" subnational2-code="US-VA-127">New Kent</location>
  <location country-code="US" subnational1-code="US-DE" subnational2-code="US-DE-001">Kent</location>
  <location country-code="US" subnational1-code="US-KY" subnational2-code="US-KY-117">Kenton</location>
  <location country-code="US" subnational1-code="US-MD" subnational2-code="US-MD-029">Kent</location>
  <location country-code="US" subnational1-code="US-MI" subnational2-code="US-MI-081">Kent</location>
  <location country-code="US" subnational1-code="US-RI" subnational2-code="US-RI-003">Kent</location>
  <location country-code="CA" subnational1-code="CA-NB" subnational2-code="CA-NB-KE">Kent</location>
  <location country-code="CA" subnational1-code="CA-ON" subnational2-code="CA-ON-KT">Chatham-Kent</location>
  <location country-code="GB" subnational1-code="GB-ENG" subnational2-code="GB-ENG-KEN">Kent</location>
</result>
```

[XML Code URL.](http://www.avianknowledge.net/ws1.0/ref/subnational2/find?match=kent&format=xml)

The following is code I have either used in the past (getData worked), or am trying to figure out.  This does not necessarily have to be used:

```
var subnational1-code="US-MI";
var subnational2-name="Kent";
var itemList = response.getElementsByTagName("result");
for(i=0;i<itemList.length){
  var d = getData(itemList.item(i));

  //  What code goes here??
  //  If (subnational2-value==subnational2-name&&subnational1-valuue=="US-MI");

}

function getData(n) {
  var d = new Object();
  var nodeList = n.childNodes;
  for (var j = 0; j < nodeList.length ; j++) {
  var node = nodeList.item(j);
  d[node.nodeName] = node.firstChild.nodeValue;
  } return d;
}
```

The output in this case should be:

```
 var output = "US-MI-081";
```

I greatly appreciate your help.  +1 and more to anybody who can provide me with a working function!  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is jQuery an option?
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: No.  This is within a Google Gadget, which will not accept or download the jQuery library, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is entirely what you where looking for, but here is a javascript way to parse it out.  Hopefully this will work for you.

```
var output = "";
var subnational1Code="US-MI";
var subnational2Name="Kent";
var itemList = document.getElementsByTagName("result");
for(var i = 0;i<itemList.length; i++){
  var d = getData(itemList.item(i));
  for(var k in d)
    if (d[k].sub1 === subnational1Code && d[k].value === subnational2Name)
      output = d[k].sub2;
}
function getData(n) {
  var objArray = new Array();
  var nodeList = n.childNodes;
  for (var j = 0; j < nodeList.length ; j++) {
  var node = nodeList.item(j);
  var o = new Object();
  o["value"] = node.firstChild.nodeValue;
  o["country"] = node.attributes["country-code"].nodeValue;
  o["sub1"] = node.attributes["subnational1-code"].nodeValue;
  o["sub2"] = node.attributes["subnational2-code"].nodeValue;
  objArray.push(o);
  } return objArray;
}

// console.log(output); //in case you wanted to debug it
```

Comment: Thanks much for the answer!  I'll check it out when I have a chance :)  I think it looks good though

Comment: Well, I'm having trouble.  I understand the code, but it's just not working.  Are there some brackets missing on lines 7-9?  Have you tested it on the URL and did it work?  Could you copy a jsFiddle or something?  I hope I'm not asking too much :-|

Comment: @wagtail Hm... seems I did find one potential problem.  When I put it into an HTML document and ran it, it was picking up text nodes (the difference between using `childNodes` and `children`).  I corrected that and [put it in a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLN9Z/).  I haven't worked with Google Gadgets and the one problem I'm concerned with is if some of the javascript is not compatible.  Lastly, when you want to put it in the production environment, I would assume you need to change `document.getElementsByTagName` to `responce.getElementsByTagName` as you had in the previous example code.

Comment: @wagtail glad to hear it! :D  If I can be of any more help, just let me know. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use XPath to retrieve the node.

Try using the document.evaluate() function:

```
var xpathResult = document.evaluate("location[@subnational1-code='US-MI' and text() = 'Kent']/@subnational2-code", itemList, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

Comment: I'm developing in a Google Gadget which likely doesn't support XPath.  I'm doing research to find what the Google Code equivalent might be.  Pure JavaScript parsing would be preferred in this situation.